# How to add a comments box in android app

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-comments

I have recently started working on an app which allows users to read news articles from a website and I would like to allow users to directly comment about the articles on facebook.

I would like to add a comments box below the article where users can write a comment and place it on their wall with the link to the article. This comment box should also load all comments other users have previously placed on facebook for the same article.

I am following the how to guide from Facebook developers which teaches me how to login with facebook, but I am a bit overwhelmed and not quite sure which guide/tutorial/part of the SDK I should use to add a comments box. So I was hoping someone who has experience with comment boxes on Android could help me out and tell me what I should be using. I don't need an in-depth description or tutorial, I just need to know what I should be using and where I can find some information about it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

[The Facebook documentation says:](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments)

`The Comments box lets people comment on content on your SITE using their Facebook profile...`

So its not for Android. :) but you can use a HTML page to show in webview.

**Tutorials HTML:**

1. [Tutorial 1](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tutorial.html)
2. [Code found on Developers.Facebook.com](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/472)

   ```
   <html>
     <head>

        <meta property="fb:app_id" content="{YOUR_APPLICATION_ID}">

     </head>

     <script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1">
     </script>

     <body>

           <div id="fb-root"></div>

           <fb:comments href="YOUR_CANONICAL_URL"></fb:comments>

     </body>
   </html>
   ```